# easy MATLAB function for computing a new vector a containing the angles such that sin(a) = v

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

I already have a vector and I'm trying to compute from this vector a new vector `a` containing the angles such that `sin(a)=v`. How can I do so?

Comment: Did you know about the inverse function arcsine?

Comment: This could have been solved with a few minutes of research. There question isn't even Matlab specific, as much as just math. Please do research before posting, and share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Inverse Sine in Degrees `asind()` and Radians `asin()`

In this example the first original vector is denoted as `v`. By taking the inverse sine you can find a vector `a` that will satisfy → `sin(a) = v`. This is simply re-arranging the equation to solve for `a`, → `a = sin^-1(v)`. To do the inverse sine in MATLAB you can use the `asin()` function.
[image: Rearranging the Equation]

---

### Important Notes:

• `sind()`,`cosd()`,`asind()`,`acosd()` → Used for arguments in terms of degrees.

• `sin()`,`cos()`,`asin()`,`acos()` →  Used for arguments in terms of radians.

```
%Generating random test vector [v]%
v = rand(5,1);

%Evaluating vector [a] by taking the inverse sine%
a = asin(v);

%Check%
if(sin(a) == v)
   fprintf("sin(a) = v\n"); 
   sin(a)
end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**